# How to listen to ALL events dispatched on the GWT Event Bus?

Tags: gwt, event-bus

I want to be able to listen to all events dispatched on the `Event Bus`, regardless of type. How can I do this?

Comment: Travis, this is a rather interesting question. If you wind up proceeding as @Thomas Broyer suggested below it'd be great if you posted some solution details for the benefit of those looking to do the same, e.g. it'd be interesting to know whether you wind up introducing additional methods to your extended event bus, etc.

Comment: I did go with Broyer's suggestion -- it seems to work fine. I'll post my solution after work today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking a cue from Thomas's suggestion, here is a sample solution:

```
    public class MyEventBus extends SimpleEventBus {

    @Override
    public void fireEvent( GwtEvent<?> event ) {
        trackEvent( "Event Fired", event.getClass().toString() );
        super.fireEvent( event );
    }

    public native void trackEvent( String category, String action ) /*-{
        $wnd._gaq.push([ '_trackEvent', category, action ]);
    }-*/;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

SimpleEventBus doesn't let you do this, but you could easily wrap or extend it and override fireEvent et al. to catch all dispatched events.